# json error is occuring when i executing the code in google collab in python

Tags: python, gradio

123-jaji/genaichatbot
code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo.launch()
```

error:

```
ValueError: When localhost is not accessible, a shareable link must be created. Please set share=True or check your proxy settings to allow access to localhost.
Colab notebook detected. To show errors in colab notebook, set debug=True in launch()
Note: opening Chrome Inspector may crash demo inside Colab notebooks.
```

i am creating a generative ai
when i asking a question it does not shows the answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include sufficient code.  There's not enough context in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error from my local machine. And the code

`export no_proxy="localhost, 127.0.0.1"` helps me.